# Is __stdcall MSVC extension?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc

ALL,

I'm trying to create a cross-platform program. One of my functions is declared as __stdcall.

It compiles fine with MSVC 2010, but g++ complains. And so I presume that it is MSVC extension?

Am I right?

Comment: @PauloTorrens, I think you meant a different page. I don't see an "stdcall" referenced...

Comment: Nothing to do with MSVC, it is the calling convention for the Windows api. G++ supports it well, but nobody ever agrees how it should be declared. Cross-platform code always needs lots of macaroni, you could, say, use `#define __stdcall __attribute(stdcall)__` when you target Windows and `#define __stdcall` if you target `*nix`.  Do keep in mind that *because* it is a winapi convention, the actual code is pretty unlikely to port well.  Nobody can tell you if you don't show us.